# React Native Hide Bottom Navigation

Tags: android, react-native

I have created a app which has bottom tab-navigation using react-navigation(https://reactnavigation.org).

There is one problem in which Android's native navigation bar has overlapped applications tab-navigation-bar.

Is there any way in which we can hide the native navigation bar in Android ?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the content doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.

```
private void hideSystemUI() 
{
     mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION 
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN 
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
}

private void showSystemUI() 
{
    mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

Comment: I am a react developer, how to apply ur solution? little guidance will be helpful :)